# Control serializer in JsonResult aka Json function in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, json, serialization

Is there a way to configure what JSON serializer is used when returning JSON via the JsonResult in the controller:

```
public ActionResult SomeJsonFunction()
{
  var x = SomeModelCode.SomeModelFunction();
  return Json(x);
}
```

It looks like the default is the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://JavaScriptSerializer).  I would love to be able to use the DataContractJsonSerializer, but cannot find any documentation on how to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [the source](http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet) to see how JsonResult is implemented.  Derive from ActionResult with your DataContractJsonSerializer implementation.  Right now it won't be easy to use the Json() helper method, but you could create your own helper method in a layer supertype controller.  Your new helper method would return your new ActionResult derivation.

Comment: That is exactly what I ended up doing.  It just instantiates the JavascriptSerializer, and is fairly trivial to write an ActionResult derived DataContractJsonResult.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!  This solved a problem we were having with circular references and the other fallbacks of the JavaScriptSerializer.