# Rename field in JsonSerializer

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, json, jsonserializer

I have a class library that I need to output via a JsonResult in the ASP.NET MVC framework. (JsonResult uses the JsonSerializer to produce its output.)

I discovered through reading the documentation that if you put `[ScriptIgnore]` on a public property/field, it will not get serialized, much like `[XmlIgnore]` for the XML serializer.

I need the equivalent functionality of `[XmlElement("elementname")]`, which specifies absolutely the name of the field/property in the output serialization. I have a field called `Elements` that needs to get serialized to a field named `elements`.

How can I accomplish this using the default JsonSerializer?

Thanks,
David

Comment: I'm confused why this would get downvoted. Its pretty relevant to anyone who wants to have a strongly-typed class library decoupled from what gets spit out to JavaScript.

Comment: From the MSDN documentation on this serializer, it doesn't appear any more attributes apply to it. This is -very- disappointing if it genuinely doesn't support it. My use case in this instance is there is a JSON.net compatible implementation of the OpenFlashChart2 object model, and I wanted to just annotate the fields with [ScriptIgnore] and whatever attribute this question yielded and then submit back to the OpenFlashChart2 team as a working ASP.NET MVC compatible library. Now it looks like I'm going to have to wrap the classes in an ASP.NET MVC wrapper with poorly named public fields.

Comment: David did you ever end up creating an ASP.NET MVC library for use with OpenFlashChart2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28VS.95%29.aspx) class?

If so ...

Add this attribute to you `Elements` field

```
[DataMember(Name = "elements")]
```

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404393/control-serializer-in-jsonresult-aka-json-function-in-asp-net-mvc) suggests how to override the use of JsonScriptSerializer to JsonDataContractSerializer.

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: No, I am using the JsonSerializer. As I mentioned, it is required because it is what JsonResult uses in the MVC framework.

Comment: Added link to SO question explaining a route to use differenet (more configurable) Json serializer.

Comment: Still not what I'm looking for, but this answers the question now and is really helpful. I might end up being forced down this road if no one can answer the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The unfortunate answer is, you cannot do it. Having said that, I am currently developing a module that will extend any object by producing at runtime an anonymous object that will follow rules from attributes, such as JsonIgnore or JsonProperty. I'll post more when I have something.

Answer (score -1):

The correct attribute for this is [JsonPropertyName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute?view=netcore-3.0).

Comment: You're answering this question 10 years after it was originally asked. This question is not about .NET Core 3.0's built in `JsonSerializer`, which of course did not exist in 2009. It is about the built-in `JsonSerializer` in now-obsolete ASP.NET MVC 2.0, prior to them switching to JSON.NET as the default serializer.