# Filtering Properties from Dto before outputting as Json

Tags: json, model-view-controller, serialization

I have a REST API for exposing quote data. Sometimes API can take specific parameters to provide data for.

General usage: `http://blah.com/quotes?symbol=MSFT`

specific usage: `http://blah.com/quotes?symbol=MSFT&params=[Symbol,Sector,Industry]`

DTO:

```
public class QuoteDto 
{
    public string CompanyName { get; private set; }
    public string Symbol { get; private set; }
    public string Exchange { get; private set; }
    public string Sector { get; private set; }
    public string Industry { get; private set; }
    . . . 
}
```

during general usage i simply serialize my DTO into Json. But when i get specific request how can i filter out unwanted params from my dto before i serialize ??

is there any third party lib to do this? I can use reflection but thats way to wonky. 
I am using ASP.NET MVC and C#

Answer (score 0):

Use a mix of two techniques - 
the first is to write your own json result.

[Control serializer in JsonResult aka Json function in ASP.Net MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404393/control-serializer-in-jsonresult-aka-json-function-in-asp-net-mvc)

http://brianreiter.org/2011/01/03/custom-jsonresult-class-for-asp-net-mvc-to-avoid-maxjsonlength-exceeded-exception/

Secondly, instead of using for ex. javascriptserializer, you would in turn use JSON.Net to manually do the serialization. This way you could exclude whatever properties you want based on your rules. A block of code from their site shows its quite simple to serialize
http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/ReadingWritingJSON.html

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);

using (JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
{
  jsonWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
  jsonWriter.WriteStartObject();
  jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("CPU");
  jsonWriter.WriteValue("Intel");

  jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("PSU");
  jsonWriter.WriteValue("500W");

  jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("Drives");
  jsonWriter.WriteStartArray();

  jsonWriter.WriteValue("DVD read/writer");
  jsonWriter.WriteComment("(broken)");

  jsonWriter.WriteValue("500 gigabyte hard drive");
  jsonWriter.WriteValue("200 gigabype hard drive");

  jsonWriter.WriteEnd();

  jsonWriter.WriteEndObject();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use NHibernate quite a bit, but it's more than I need to send down everything in the JSON.

While hacky, I like to use a `Dictionary<string, object>` and then just add the members I want to send down.

```
return Json(someDict);
```